# how to call a function $_SESSION[usr]->logout() inside <a>

Tags: php, html, session, onclick

I have a class named **User** which has a function named `logout()`. I create an instance of this class in **index.php** and i pass it's value to `$_SESSION[usr]` before i call memberspage.php . In memberspage.php i have a link named logout which when clicked i want the `logout()` function to run and also send the user to **index.php**. For this purpose i've done something like this.

```
<a href="index.php" onclick= "$_SESSION[usr]->logout()">Log out</a>
```

I know that -> causes the problem but i don't know how to fix it. thnx for your time.

The following code worked for me

```
<a href="index.php" onclick ="alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]->logOut(); ?>')">Log out</a>
```

but there is a problem. If i go to the page(memberspage.php) where the above code is and i press the back arrow (not logout link) the logOut() function will still be used(the session is destroyed and i will have to log in again to access memberpage.php) . I don't get it because i thought that the only way to call the logOut() function was to click on Log out link.

Comment: I think it is job of AJAX

Comment: where and how did you define logout function ?

Comment: onclick= "$_SESSION[usr]->logout()" this is totally wrong. It wont have any effect. You could directly put a link logout file code that logs out the user.

Comment: i don't have the code in front of me at the moment  but i used $_SESSION[usr]->logout() outside of <a> and it works fine. I just can't find how to use it inside onclick.

Comment: @profchaos you can use it directly like that..

Comment: Than you have to use ajax because first of all you cannot write php code without <?php ?> tag and it is also not a good idea to use it. I will opt you to use AJAX for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$_SESSION[usr]->logout()` is working for you as you said in your comment. I don't know how.

But here is just for calling a php function inside anchor tag.It's totally depend on your function response.

```
    <?php
        function usr(){
            return "abc";
        }

    ?>

    <a href="index.php" onclick ="alert('<?php echo usr(); ?>')">Log out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First i suggest that you change your use of session you can create a page for example session.php where all your session is place, it can also be the re directory page of your login page.

like this one named login.php

create in your form make action redirect to session.php

i also suggest that all your php codes of login are inside the session.php then make this one.

```
   <?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "mydb;

//database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pass, $db);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    //$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
    //$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '" .$username. "' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        if($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
                $_SESSION['type'] = $data['type'];


          if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]))
 {

                    if($data['type'] == 'admin'){
                        header('location: admin.php');
                    }

                  else  if($data['type'] == 'customer'){
                        header('location: customerhome.php');
                    }//header('location: uservalidation.php');




 }

            }
        }
    else{
//header('location: #');



        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Invalid no?")';

        echo '</script>';

          header('location: logind.php');

    }

}


?>
```

then create another page which is logout.php

put this code inside:

```
  <?php

session_start();
header('location: index.php');
session_destroy();


?>
```

then save put the a link your page for logout.php

Answer (score 1):

Add file `logout.php` and put into them your logout implementation:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$_SESSION[usr]->logout();

echo json_encode(['message' => 'ok']);
```

And call this file with AJAX:

```
<script>
function logout() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/logout.php'
    }).then(function (res) {
        window.location.href = '/';
    });
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick= "logout();">Log out</a>
```